# Website notifications in Webview Android App

Tags: android, webview, notifications

I have developed a WebView app for a social network website. I want to add notifications of the website in the WebView app. When one user sends message or friend request, the second user must get a notification.

Is there any way to show all that notifications from the website in the WebView app?

Please help.

Comment: Hello @Rahul Pathak from your question i would like to ask question like All the users installed Webview app and from app they are send messages and friend request? And the person who are installed this he/she will get the notification? Am i right?

Comment: Yes Sir @NileshPanchal. If user 1 sends friend request/message to another user 2 then only user 2 will get the notification.

Comment: Sir @NileshPanchal Can i get the user details like id/user name/email id from the webview?

Comment: @RahulPathak Did you solve it? If so, I'm very interested by the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want notification in webview than you must have to register every device with firebase when app installed for sending push notification

And whenever action is performed from webview than from backend the push notification will fire with "PayLoad" and from there we are displaying the notification to one devices to other devices using webview app.

Note : You Must need to register device for push notification  using firebase.

Comment: Sir by using firebase, How user 1 will get the notification from user 2. Can a user get a particular notification about message/friend request using firebase? or All users will get the same notification.