# How to display website notifications as app notifications android studio webview

Tags: java, android, webview

Tried searching the solution here but it requires to reg. every user in firebase
[Website notifications in Webview Android App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087342/website-notifications-in-webview-android-app)

Every other answer to such question ends up to firebase,

how to implement it for normal website notification, in our website the user gets personalized notifications too.

has anyone tried any other solution to this?
since its just normal website notification thats needed to be displayed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991937/android-webview-push-notification

Answer (score -1):

You may use javascript to communicate to the WebView to show notifications:

1. create JavascriptInterface in android:

   ```
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Receive messages from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String message) {
            // push notifications to android system ....
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
   ```
2. add javascript interface to webview:

`webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "AndroidPush");`

3. execute push notification in javascript code of web page:

   ```
    // on message recivied from server.
    if (AndroidPush) {
        // call android webview to push notifications.
        AndroidPush.showToast('message...');
    } else {
        // call notification api of browser.
        ...
    }
    ......
   ```

Comment: do I need to add these in android studio code only or do I need to put some of it on the website too?

Comment: Is there an example github project for this